# Combine two strings in Java

Tags: java, string, string-concatenation, bukkit

I have been making a very simple bukkit plugin for my server just for personal use.
I made a command called players, when someone with the permission ("broadcaster.players"), it would display a list of the servers player.
I also wanted to have it display the players gamemode in-game. But I don't know how to put both of them next to each other.

My Code:

```
if(cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("players")){
  Player player = (Player) sender;
  if(sender instanceof Player){
    if(sender.hasPermission("broadcaster.players")){
      sender.sendMessage(player.getName());
    }
  }
}
```

Where it says `sender.sendMessage(player.getName());`, I would like  to display on the same line the gamemode.
so I tried:

```
sender.sendMessage(player.getName()player.getGameMode());
```

of course this never worked and i am not sure what to do, can anyone suggest to me what i could do, 
My code is pretty messy but I'm fairly new, so I don't know a lot of things, this is my first coding project and i need tons of help!

Thanks for your patience

Comment: For better perfomance, use this : new StringBuilder().append("word1").append("word2").toString();

Answer (score 2):

To combine two strings in Java, you can use the `+` operator, for example:

```
String first = "Hello, ";
String second = "World"!;
String str = first + second;
```

`str` is now equal to `first + second`, which means `"Hello, " + "World!"`, which therefore means that `str` is now equal to the string `"Hello, World!"`.

In your case, you could do:

```
sender.sendMessage(player.getName() + player.getGameMode());
```

But, there would be no space in between them, so, I would recommend adding a space, or a colon between them for readability purposes:

```
sender.sendMessage(player.getName() + ": " + player.getGameMode());
```

If the player's name is `jojodmo`, and their gamemode is `SURVIVAL`, with `sender.sendMessage(player.getName() + player.getGameMode());`, the message `jojodmoSURVIVAL` would be sent.

Yet, with `sender.sendMessage(player.getName() + ": " + player.getGameMode());`, the message `jojodmo: SURVIVAL` would be sent.

To get more information on strings in Java, I recommend that you visit  [the Java Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/strings.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate two Strings using the `+` operator:

```
sender.sendMessage(player.getName() + ": " + player.getGameMode());
```

Answer (score 0):

Java allows the `+` operator to concatenate strings:

```
String hi = "hi";
String zebra = "kangaroo";
System.out.println(hi + ", Mr. " + zebra); // outputs hi, Mr. kangaroo.
```

Secondly, since String is an object in Java, it has a method, `concat()`, to concatenate strings to other strings. If you're a big jQuery fan like me, you might want to also consider:

```
String hi = "hi";
String zebra = "kangaroo";
System.out.println(hi.concat(", Mr. ").concat(zebra)); // outputs hi, Mr. kangaroo.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send him a list of players:

```
String send = "";
for(Player p1 : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers() {
send+=p1.getName() + "(" + p1.getGameMode() + ") ";
}
p.sendMessage(send);
```

This should send to the player a list of all players and their gamemodes.

Comment: This should use a StringBuilder instead of string concat